# Trying to Get JPA/Hibernate working with REST -- TransactionRequiredException: No Transaction is in progress error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've been trying to get Hibernate / JPA working with my simple Spring 3.2 REST application.

Hibernate/JPA successfully create my table in MySQL, but the transaction fails once it gets into the Repository -- saying no transaction is in progress. I'm really out of my element here and not even sure how to troubleshoot this as it seems most of the code is happening behind the scenes in xml.

Any help much appreciated.
**UPDATE -- jpaContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.saltcitywifi"></context:component-scan>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" >
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />

</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/salt_city_wifi?autoReconnect=true" />
    <property name="username" value="wifi_admin" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HotSpotController {
@Autowired
private HotSpotService hotSpotService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/hotSpots", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<HotSpot> getHotSpots() {
    hotSpotService = new HotSpotServiceImpl();
    List<HotSpot> spots = hotSpotService.getAllHotSpots();
    return spots;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/hotSpot", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
HotSpot addHotSpot(@RequestBody HotSpot hotSpot) {
    hotSpotService.addHotSpot(hotSpot);
    return hotSpot;
}

}
```

Service:

```
@Service("hotSpotService")
@Transactional
public class HotSpotServiceImpl implements HotSpotService {
@Autowired
private HotSpotRepository hotSpotRepository;
private AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

public List<HotSpot> getAllHotSpots() {
    List<HotSpot> spots = new ArrayList<HotSpot>();
    HotSpot spot;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        spot = new HotSpot("location " + i, "http://www.url" + i + ".com",
                counter.incrementAndGet());
        spots.add(spot);
    }
    return spots;
}

public HotSpot getHotSpotById(long id) {
    HotSpot spot = new HotSpot("New Spot", "New Url", id);
    return spot;
}

@Transactional
public HotSpot addHotSpot(HotSpot hotSpot) {
    return hotSpotRepository.addHotSpot(hotSpot);

}

}

@Repository("hotSpotRepository")
public class HotSpotRepositoryImpl implements HotSpotRepository {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;


public HotSpot addHotSpot(HotSpot hotSpot) {
    em.persist(hotSpot);
    em.flush();
    return hotSpot;
}

}
```

Comment: Please post your spring config file here. You need to configure the annotation-driven, tx:transaction etc in the configuration to get this working.. also set the propagation on the @transactional to requires

Comment: `hotSpotService = new HotSpotServiceImpl();` doing this will create an instance of a class that Spring will know anything about. Remove that line. `@Autowired private HotSpotRepository hotSpotRepository;` should be enough because Spring will create just one instance of HotSpotRepository and inject it in your Controller. When you take the matter in own your hands (by manually creating that instance) Spring will not be able to help you (for example, by adding transactions to methods).

Comment: @Zeus I updated the post with my jpaContext.xml let me know if you would like to see other config files.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I removed the call to new -- I actually haven't been working on that method in the controller though. I've only been working on the /hotSpot route with POST request. I'm still having the same error -- no transaction in progress error. Thank you both for your help, hopefully I can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Here's my code in full: https://github.com/paniclater/saltcitywifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally figured out what was going on here:

I have two component scanners, one for my controllers in servlet-config.xml and one for my JPA stuff in jpaContext.xml.

They were both scanning basically my whole application:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.saltcitywifi" />
```

When I forced the component scanner for controllers to only look in the controller package:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.saltcitywifi.controller" />
```

All of a sudden my requests worked and were processed in the database.

I can only assume since my servlet-config.xml configuration only contains:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.saltcitywifi.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

That Spring was somehow letting servlet-config.xml register the JPA beans, so the transactional annotations weren't being picked up. This is still confusing to me, so if anyone can help explain why this occurs that would be very helpful. I might just ask another stack overflow question on this subject.

Comment: :-) the problem is that `servlet-context.xml` scans all the packages, it finds controllers and services, but for services even if you have @Transactional, it's missing the actual `transactionManager` `tx:annotation-driven` which are in an xml file. Because of this in the Controller you get a simple @Service bean with no @Transactional behavior. It doesn't matter you have another component scanning in `jpa-context.xml` because everthing starts from Controllers in the usage flow: you access a web page, a controller is called, the controller calls the service, service is not transactional.

Comment: Thank you, @AndreiStefan, that makes sense, I will update my question and answer to try and clarify the situation for others who may have this same problem. One thing that I wonder about: I kind of just solved this by guessing -- is there any better way to debug so I can see what is going on if I have another conflicting configuration problem in the future? Debugging these .xml files is a completely mysterious process to me.

Comment: You can look in the DEBUG logs for messages related to application contexts. There is the root app context that gets created. And there is the web app context that has as a parent the root context. In logs you should see the bean names that one app context contains listed as a single line with commas. You can spot both app contexts in logs and look for the beans created. If you see the same controller defined in both these contexts then you know your app is in trouble.

Comment: Actually, you don't need DEBUG, INFO is enough. Here's one example: `Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5850abcc: defining beans [exampleService,myListener,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,com.LogAspect#0];`